# how to solve errors in an sql query that returns an error saying no database chosen for select statement and it suggest select default DB?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select if(l1,l2
    concatinate(av_prdct_l1, av_prdct_l2)) as level, count(orders) as ord, sum(price) as sales, sum(price-cost/price) as margin, 1-sum(pricevat)/1.14/sum(av_prdct.pricevat/1.14) as discrate from db.av_sales_order_items
    left join av_prdct
    on db.av_sales_order_items.orders=av_prdct.orders
where net=1 and order_date=currentdate()-1 and l1 is not null
group by l 
order by sales desc "Example"
```

Comment: did you try using "USE database_name" before running the query?

Comment: @marcosh That's good advice, but keep in mind that's for MySQL. Other RDBMS systems use different methods. Granted, this one is tagged MySQL :P

Comment: @Zarathuztra I saw the tag MySQL, so I supposed it was MySQL... thanks for your observation anyway!

Comment: execute query `USE yourdatabase_name`...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for the database software you are using.

For example, if you're running MySQL run: USE  where  is the name of the database, if done via CLI. If you're doing this programmatically, consult the documentation used there. For example, using mysqli in PHP

Assuming an active connection:

```
mysqli_select_db(<databaseName>);
```

again where database name is a string of the name of the database. You call this before making any queries.

Other RDBMS systems use other methods, for example, on command line DB2 you would issue

```
CONNECT TO <databaseName> USER <userName> USING <password>
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicit use of `USE` command is *not mandatory* so long as you use the database qualifiers on the tables or other database specific objects used in your statements.

Looking close at your statements posted, the error of *DB not selected* must be on the `desc Example` statement.

The first `select ...` statement has db qualifiers included and hence is correct, though it had some other syntax errors.

On the *Example* table you can try:

```
desc my_db_name.Example;
```

Replace the `my_db_name` in the above example with your valid database name and it should be working.

MySQL documentation says:

> USE db_name
>   The USE db_name statement tells MySQL to use the db_name
>   database as the default (current) database for subsequent statements.
>   The database remains the default until the end of the session or
>   another USE statement is issued:
>
> USE db1;
>   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable;   # selects from db1.mytable
>
>   USE db2;
>
>   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable;   # selects from db2.mytable
>
> Making a particular database the default by means of the USE statement
>   does not preclude you from accessing tables in other databases. The
>   following example accesses the author table from the db1 database and
>   the editor table from the db2 database:
>
> USE db1; SELECT author_name,editor_name FROM author,db2.editor
>   WHERE author.editor_id = db2.editor.editor_id;

Answer (score 0):

if you are connecting to mysql from command line, you can use below command for connecting to db

> mysql -u [username] -p [database_name you want to connect to]

OR

> mysql -u [username] -p

--after connecting to DB--

> use [database_name]

And if you are using UI client like 'MySQL workbench'; you can give default database while creating 'New Connection' OR can change DB from Left Pane available.

Comment: thanks guys the mistake was in the first round bracket before concatinate so when I took it out it worked fine. appreciate your responses.